# jquery fadein , fadeout isnt working

Tags: jquery

```
             <div id="ranking">
                                    <div id="ranking_wrapper">
                                        <h5>Select site ranking</h5>
                                        <img src="images/star.png" width="23" height="23" alt="" border="0">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sitename" value="webcamking">
                                        <input type="radio" name="rank" value="1">1
                                        <input type="radio" name="rank" value="2">2
                                        <input type="radio" name="rank" value="3" checked="checked">3
                                        <input type="radio" name="rank" value="4">4
                                        <input type="radio" name="rank" value="5">5
                                        <img src="/images/star.png" width="23" height="23" alt="" border="0">
                                        <p><input type="submit" value="Rank This Site" id="rank_submit"></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="response" style="display:none;" >
                                        <h5>Loading...</h5>
                                        <img src='images/ajax_loader.gif' class='img_center'/>
                                    </div>
                                        </div>
                            <script>
                                        $("#rank_submit").click(function(){

                                          $("#ranking_wrapper").fadeOut(0);
                                            $("#response").fadeIn('slow');
                                            $("#response").fadeOut('slow',function(){

                                                 $("#ranking").html('<div id="response" style="display:none;"> Thanks you for ranking webca.</div>');
                                            });

                                        });
                            </script>
```

The problem is that as soon after the element is faded out, it doesnt add the div element to the ranking div.

```
         $("#response").fadeOut('slow',function(){

                                                 $("#ranking").html('<div id="response" style="display:none;"> Thanks you for ranking webca.</div>');
                                            });
```

the callback function isnt working..why?!!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- be sure to execute the fadeOut when `#response` is already into the dom
- be sure `#ranking` exists
- the `div` you're injecting has `display: none` (so you cannot see it)

Comment: All 4 of your points failed. all the divs exist..I dont add them dynamically.. append doesnt make a change

Comment: dammit.. I know what the problem was.. it was the display attribute, set accidently to none.. therefore it didnt appear

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd so do I get the check mark since I was first

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd this is not my answer

Answer (score 1):

Because you have this

```
<div id="response" style="display:none;">
```

You are changing the html into that, so it is display none and therefore you won't see it

Answer (score 1):

Why You have add the property style="display:none"

Replace the code

```
$("#ranking").html('<div id="response" style="display:none;"> Thanks you for ranking webca.</div>');


 $("#ranking").html('<div id="response"> Thanks you for ranking webca.</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
style="display:none;"
```

from your code.Its hiding your html.

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/XcPd5/.